# Subscribe to bitFlyer WebSocket

Tags: python, websocket

I have set up websocket connections to multiple cryptocurrency exchanges but I'm having difficulty connecting to bitFlyer's.

My code is as follows:

```
import websocket
import json

def on_message(ws, message):
    msg = json.loads(message)
    print(msg)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    ws.send(json.dumps({"method":"subscribe", "channel":"lightning_executions_FX_BTC_JPY"}))

while True:   
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        #websocket.enableTrace(True)
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.lightstream.bitflyer.com/json-rpc",
                                    on_message=on_message,
                                    on_error=on_error,
                                    on_close=on_close)
        ws.on_open = on_open
        ws.run_forever()
```

I have tried many many variations of my on_open() message and most result in a `### closed ###
Invalid close opcode.` error.

Unfortunately their documentation does not contain a Python sample located [HERE](https://lightning.bitflyer.jp/docs?lang=en#json-rpc-2.0-over-websocket).

Any help in sending the correct message is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the format of message you sent was wrong, check the following reference from https://lightning.bitflyer.jp/docs/playgroundrealtime, guess it will solve.

```
# pip install websocket-client
import websocket
import json
CHANNEL = "lightning_board_snapshot_<productCode>"

def on_message(ws, message):
    message = json.loads(message)
    if message["method"] == "channelMessage":
        print("{} {}".format(message["params"]["channel"], message["params"]["message"]))

def on_open(ws):
    ws.send(json.dumps({"method": "subscribe", "params": {"channel": CHANNEL}}))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    // note: reconnection handling needed.
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.lightstream.bitflyer.com/json-rpc",
                              on_message = on_message, on_open = on_open)
    ws.run_forever()
```